# Should we be upgrading away from ubuntu.components 0.1?

Tags: application-development, programming, libraries, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Should we be upgrading away from ubuntu.components 0.1 in our ubuntu applications?

I am working on one of the core apps, and many were unsure as to whether the current library (1.1 I think) offers anything like performance increases, or graphical tweaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu SDK promises to maintain backwards compatibility. As far as I can remember Ubuntu Components 1.1 was created with the introduction of new widgets like combo box, additional API changes, some performance tweaks etc.

Core Apps are the first wave of consumers of the Ubuntu SDK followed by other 3rd party. I personally feel that we should be striving to be as close as possible to upstream in this regard and encourage 3rd party app devs to do the same.

So yes, it is best to leave 0.1 behind and upgrade to Ubuntu Components 1.1.